# Bootstrap margin top responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, margin

I have a problem with aligning a bootstrap element to the top.

This is the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="image.png" class="profileimg" />"
        <h1 class="view_name">John Doe</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.view_name {
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

The H1 element won't pull up to the top. How can it be achieved that the image is left and the h1 element right, but in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Boostrap's `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes.

https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/u5suaLgw/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="image.png" class="profileimg pull-left" />"
        <h1 class="view_name pull-right">John Doe</h1>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Use `pull-left` instead of `pull-right` in the `h1`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="image.png" class="profileimg pull-left" />
        <h1 class="view_name pull-left">John Doe</h1>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/u5suaLgw/1/

Comment: Thanks for your respons. But I mean that the image is left and the H1 is right next to it on the right but on the top.

Comment: @OleB. the update worked for you or you are still facing issue?